# How can i add icon into my app?

Tags: iphone, ios

In my app the icon shows in simulator but it is not shown in iphone. What is the problem? I followed all the apple preferred size icons.
Please help me.

Comment: Delete the existing app from phone and clear the targets in Xcode and run it again

Answer (score 5):

If you have followed all the recommended by guidelines by apple, the icon will be displayed. Sometimes deleting the app from device and adding it again, does the trick.